# SetTimeOut in React hook does not allow writing to input text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to wait 2 seconds when an input text contains text and make a request to my API. I wrote this function as a react hook called useBounce:

```
const useDebounce = (func, milliseconds) => {
    const time = milliseconds || 400
    let timer
    return event => {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
        timer = setTimeout(func, time, event)
    }
}

export default useDebounce
```

So I have an input with an onChange that when I try to write react it doesn't allow me to do it and the call function to my API doesn't execute:

```
 const searchDebounce = useDebounce((e) => {
     setInput(e.target.value);
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }, 2000) 

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={ searchDebounce }
        value={input}
        className='border-2 border-cyan-500'
      />
    </>
  )
```

For now I am trying to see what is written in the input through the console but since it does not allow me to write, the console is blank.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

it works with your code with minor changes, i dont know the exact why tho

```
const useDebounce = (func, milliseconds) => {
  const time = milliseconds || 400;
  let timer;
  return (event) => {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(func, time, event.target?.value);
  };
};

const [input, setInput] = useState('');

const searchDebounce = useDebounce((e) => {
  setInput(e);
}, 2000);


  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={searchDebounce}
        className="border-2 border-cyan-500"
      />
    </>
  );
```

the thing is, if you want to implement debounce function to search something by your input, you shouldn't debounce the the function to update input state (`setInput`), since it will also delay the text input value when user is typing in.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example for same

```
const useDebounce = (value, delay) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value]);

  return debouncedValue;
};
```

the above is my custom `useDebounce` hook and to delay the input check below code

```
export const Debouncing = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const delayedValue= useDebounce(value, 2000);

 // useEffect(()=>{
  //apiCall()  api call goes here
  //},[delayedValue]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Debouncing</h1>
      Current: {value} - Debounced: {delayedValue}
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        style={{ margin: "30px" }}
        placeholder="input search"
      />
    </>
  );
};
```